# Help to make jQuery simple

Tags: jquery, html

How can i make this shooter.

It does what it should but it is very long. Oh and I need to run a function for each number.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="moremenu" class="hide">
<ul>
<li>View count</li>
<li>Click count</li>
<li>Profile</li>
<li>Inbox</li>
<li>Uploads</li>
<li>TV</li>
<li>Notes</li>
<li>More</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="status"></div>
```

And this is my jQuery

```
    $("#moremenu ul li").click(function () {

    var index = $('#moremenu ul li').index(this);
    var clickval = $('#moremenu ul li').text(this);

    //$('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    if(index == 0){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 1){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 2){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 3){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 4){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 5){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 6){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 7){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    if(index == 8){
        $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var index = $('#moremenu ul li').index(this);
var clickval = $('#moremenu ul li').text(this);

if(index >= 0 && index <= 8){
    $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

This is simple JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```
    var index = $('#moremenu ul li').index(this);
    var clickval = $('#moremenu ul li').text(this);

    if(index >= 0 && index <= 8){
       $('.status').prepend('<p>click index was '+index+'</p>').prepend('<p>You clicked '+clickval+'</p>').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    }
```

Comment: That condition is always true.